# Equivalent of Python's request.session.auth in C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, python, restsharp

In Python I can successfully make a request (with authorization passing) by doing:

```
def send_request(self, url, public_key, secret_key):
   session = requests.session()
   session.auth = (public_key, secret_key)
   return session.get(url)
```

I'm trying to replicate this in C# but it's **not authorizing:**

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url_stuff, Method.GET);
request.AddHeader(public_key, secret_key);
return client.Execute(request).Content;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session.auth = (public_key, secret_key)
```

in python is shorthand for Basic authentication, with `public_key` being user name and `secret_key` a password. To do the same with `RestClient` you need to:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(public_key, secret_key);
return client.Execute(request).Content;
```