# How do I know if my HTTP port requests worked in c#?

Tags: c#, post, webclient

So I manage to create a post requests but I have no idea on how to know if it worked?
How can I get the html code of the website after the requests?

here is my code:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    var method = "POST"; // If your endpoint expects a GET then do it.
    var parameters = new NameValueCollection();

    parameters.Add("utf8", "✓");
    parameters.Add("style", data);
    parameters.Add("size", size);
    parameters.Add("commit", "add to basket");

    var response_data = client.UploadValues(url_add_to_cart, method, parameters);
```

Moreover, after this post requests I need to do another post requests with the same session I used before. Is it possible by doing everything in the same webclient??

Thank you very much for your answers!
If you need more info I'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `try` `catch` block in this line :

```
try 
{
   var response_data = client.UploadValues(url_add_to_cart, method, parameters);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

If you get an error on your HTTP request, program should execute the catch block.
Try debbuging your code and see what is inside the `response_data` var.

HTTP error are metioned here btw :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-errors

Comment: It doesn't go in the catch! thank you! 
the problem is that I can't do another requests after that. it's like this one didn't do it. in python I used to do requests.session but I didn't find any equivalent in c#

Comment: Check this post to see what is inside your html page : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934508/printing-a-formatted-html-page-in-c-sharp

and this post for request.session equivalent 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490511/equivalent-of-pythons-request-session-auth-in-c-sharp-net

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` will throw `WebException` if the server returns a non-success (200) code.

Examine `WebException.Status` for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx

Comment: it is kinda hard to understand ... I tried to print the html page of my page after and I saw that my post work. (so my requests adds an item to the bag), when I try to go on another page well my item is no longer in the page. I don't know how to fix that. I used requests.session in python but with c# I find nothing on this